# How to get first object of extended class in Laravel 8

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I have a class Person with its table in the database called people. I extended the class Person to two different classes: Client and Employee. Both are different in the actions they perform in the program, but basically both are defined by the value of one column persontype_id (Of course there is a model PersonType).

I can do stuff like:

```
$clients = Client::where( 'persontype_id', 1 )->get(); // because PersonType = 1 means clients
```

But is there a way to scope that for the entire model, so I can do stuff like:

```
$client = Client::all(); // and I get only clients without Employees?
```

Something like SoftDeletes trait, that ignores the deleted objects when it performs queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an article by Caleb Porzio https://tighten.co/blog/extending-models-in-eloquent/ who was showing how to do it with a static column type. He even has a package for it. My solution adds the relationship to the global scope (personTypes) and the method looks like this:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('personTypes', function ($query) {
            return $query->where('slug', 'client' );
        });
    });
}
```